# ActiveAdmin max_width not working - why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am working with ActiveAdmin in Rails and I want to have a max column width. I researched the docs and it looks like there is a max_width selector, but it's not working for this column. Here is my code:

```
column :utility_url, max_width: "200px", sortable: 'meter.url' do |meter|
  link_to meter.url, meter.url if meter.url
end
```

Comment: Whats the html Output

Comment: <td class="col col-utility_url"><a href="(url is too long to show)"></a></td>

Comment: Should work. Pls Report at github